# "quote" command in the shell

Tags: command-line, bash

What is the usage of the command `quote`? I haven't found any info about it, it isn't among the executable files in `/bin` folders, and it cannot be found among Bash built-ins. It seems that it only prints its first parameter, like an `echo` command and nothing more.

Comment: it just adds the quotes

Comment: Just poking around, I found a utility called shell-quote which is similar to quote, but has some uses with things like ssh and for debugging bash scripts. Thought I'd include it here as a footnote. 'http://linux.die.net/man/1/shell-quote'

Comment: Feels like a WTF to have such a common word, `quote`, used for such obscure purpose... No prefix to mark it "internal", no documentation, nothing, unless you go digging in implementation details of the advanced completion mechanics of the distro. I find this a little disturbing.

Comment: It becomes even more obscure for the person, whose native language isn't English. Like me, for example. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## What is it?

I noticed that this command does not work in my shell ([fish, friendly interactive shell](http://fishshell.com/)). It seems like it does only work in bash (Ubuntu's default).

```
chocobai@pc ~> /bin/bash 
chocobai@pc:~$ quote asdf
'asdf'chocobai@pc:~$ 

chocobai@pc:~$ type quote
quote is a function.
quote ()
{ 
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
```

## What does it do? What can it be used for?

It adds the quotes but no newline. It also escapes single quotes in a way that's suitable for bash. It can be useful in scripts to quote a variable or some other kind of string. You need this for example for paths/parameters with spaces. Although there are other ways to do this.

It's really strange I could not find any documentation (in the web) about it. But well, it's easy to see what it does.

Comment: `which` is useless, both in interactive shells and in scripts. Use `type` instead. `type quote` will tell you it's a function, and even shows the function definition. Run `help type` for more on the `type` builtin.

Comment: You're right, thanks. I saw the answer above which also used type to find out what it is. Well, thanks to 'which' I knew that it wasn't an executable in /bin/ or so, because it did not return any path. I think it was still kind of useful. But you are right, I'll add type.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 12.04 this function is really described in `/etc/bash_completion`, which is sourced by `~/.bashrc` by default, not by `/etc/bash.bashrc` where the section regarding `/etc/bash_completion` is commented out. Also `/usr/share/bash-completion/` folder is absent in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 10):

`quote` is a function that is defined (here on my Debian system, but I guess it's the same on Ubuntu) in the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, which itself is sourced by `/etc/bash.bashrc` at Bash's startup.

I would never use this function! If you need to quote stuff so as to be safely usable by a shell, please use `printf` with the `%q` modifier, as:

```
printf '%q\n' "Hello my friend I like 'single quotes' as well as \"double quotes\""
```

In fact, even this is very rarely used, there are always better strategies for high-level stuff as we, users, usually do. This `quote` thing is used internally by some obscure stuff we don't even want to know about. This `quote` function is probably a vendor/distribution-specific (read Debian-specific) and is probably not portable at all, and might even change in future releases.

**Edit.** I've just checked on an Ubuntu 12.04 system, and the `quote` function is defined in `/etc/bash_completion`, sourced by `/etc/bash.bashrc`, itself sourced by `/etc/profile`.

How did I determine this? using a little of heuristic:

- Check if `quote` appears in `/etc/profile`:

  ```
  grep '\bquote\b' /etc/profile
  ```

  No. Go to next step.
- What are the files sourced by `/etc/profile`?

  ```
  grep '[[:space:]]\.[[:space:]]' /etc/profile
  ```

  I have `$i` (need to look into the source for what this sources, but in this case it's the files `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` if any (and if readable) and `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Looking in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.
- Is `quote` in `/etc/bash.bashrc`? yes/no , etc...

Comment: `quote` does actually escape single quotes, so it is usable by the shell. It works just as well as `printf %q` for this use-case.

Comment: @Flimm use at your own risks!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I think **printf %q** does not properly handle tilde (**~**). Try this: `my_str='~/.bashrc'; echo ' Expected:' "$my_str"; bash -c "echo '    quote:' $(quote "$my_str")"; bash -c "echo 'printf %q:' $(printf '%q\n' "$my_str")"`. You would see something like `Expected: ~/.bashrc`, `quote: ~/.bashrc` and `printf %q: /home/your_username/.bashrc`.

Comment: @Rockallite: I just tried it and it works a expected...

Comment: If you want to skip straight to the source, you can use `(shopt -s extdebug; declare -F quote)`, which tells you the function name, line number it is defined at, and filename it is defined in.

Answer (score 3):

`quote` is a function:

```
quote () 
{ 
    local quoted=${1//\'/\'\\\'\'};
    printf "'%s'" "$quoted"
}
```

This function is defined somewhere in a bash initialization file. More precisely, if you are using Ubuntu 13.04, you can find it in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` at the line 142.

Use the following command to check it:

```
type quote
```

Its purpose is evidently clear.

Comment: What it *does* is clear - but why you would want to do it may not be. 

For the avoidance of doubt: it would be used for taking a variable such as ```$INPUT```, that may contain spaces, quotes or other characters, and returning a string that is definitely only treated as a single argument by bash.